# Why do I only have 304 MB of available storage space?

Tags: htc-desire, internal-storage, app2sd

I have AlphaRev Oxygen R2, 4Ext Touch Recovery, AN-Droid 2.2.0 with Android 2.3.3 on my HTC Desire. But I have only 304 MB of available internal storage space after the first boot up. Now I installed Shazam and it shrank down to 296 MB.

Shouldn't this number stay the same when I install an app? I mean I have formatted my SD card in 4Ext and created a 2 GB Ext4 partition for apps. Are the apps being installed on internal memory anyway? How do I check that? And if so, how do I tell it to install to the SD-Ext partition instead?

This ROM is supposed to come with integrated App2SD+. Ain't that right? If not, can you suggest another ROM that has integrated App2SD+ or tell me how to set it up manually?

[image: 304 MB available]

I want memory, man!! This stupid phone comes with only 147 MB of memory available for the user apps and data. I don't know what the hell they were thinking when they designed it.

**In response to Izzy**

This is the output of the `mount` command.

```
sh-3.2# mount
mount
rootfs / rootfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
/sys/kernel/debug /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /app-cache tmpfs rw,relatime,size=8192k,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock3 /system yaffs2 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock4 /cache yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock5 /system/data yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /data ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,commit=50,bar
rier=0,nobh,stripe=64,data=writeback,noauto_da_alloc 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:1 /mnt/sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,u
id=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset
=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:1 /mnt/secure/asec vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relat
ime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,ioch
arset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure tmpfs ro,relatime,size=0k,mode=000 0 0
/dev/block/dm-0 /mnt/asec/se.fmckl.regnr-1 vfat ro,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,relatime
,uid=1000,fmask=0222,dmask=0222,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mix
ed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/dm-1 /mnt/asec/com.fingersoft.benjibananas-2 vfat ro,dirsync,nosuid,n
odev,relatime,uid=1000,fmask=0222,dmask=0222,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,
shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
sh-3.2#
```

Output of the `df` command.

```
sh-3.2# df
df
/dev: 207168K total, 64K used, 207104K available (block size 4096)
/mnt/asec: 207168K total, 0K used, 207168K available (block size 4096)
/mnt/obb: 207168K total, 0K used, 207168K available (block size 4096)
/app-cache: 8192K total, 0K used, 8192K available (block size 4096)
/system: 256000K total, 213132K used, 42868K available (block size 4096)
/cache: 40960K total, 1388K used, 39572K available (block size 4096)
/system/data: 151168K total, 113812K used, 37356K available (block size 4096)
/data: 2064144K total, 444856K used, 1619288K available (block size 4096)
/mnt/sdcard: 28544368K total, 9550336K used, 18994032K available (block size 163
84)
/mnt/secure/asec: 28544368K total, 9550336K used, 18994032K available (block siz
e 16384)
/mnt/asec/se.fmckl.regnr-1: 3124K total, 1040K used, 2084K available (block size
 4096)
/mnt/asec/com.fingersoft.benjibananas-2: 33212K total, 30996K used, 2216K availa
ble (block size 4096)
sh-3.2#
```

Does this make any sense?

Comment: Looks like you've bought the wrong device then (and *I* don't know what *you've* thought when you bought it ;). Apps get installed into internal storage by default. Even with App2SD (as you've already applied that tag, follow it for closer information) you can only move apps supporting this to your card, which will move *parts* of them.

Comment: May thoughts exactly! Right after I posted that comment. The fact is I had already bought the Samsung Galaxy S. But my friends were all over me about their precious HTC Desire. So I gave in to the pressure and returned the Galaxy S in exchange for the HTC Desire. I don't think I even booted up the Galaxy S, not even once. But little did I know that it came with so little memory. It was not even 512 MB but only 147 MB available for user data. The Galaxy S came with 2048 MB I think. But it's easy to be wise afterwards, you know.

Comment: How did you resize the screenshot image? Is there an image resizer tool here at SU that I'm not aware of?... I thought about resizing it but didn't have time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer my own question here. The short answer is: get a ROM that just works! *(No, not a room, a ROM! Get a ROM!)*

Here is the same screenshot image of the `SD & phone storage` menu, this time with a ROM called [SuperNova](https://supernova.droidzone.in/). You can find an installation guide [here](https://supernova.droidzone.in/category/installation/).

[image: 1.86 GB available (low res)]

As you can see from the image I now have 1.86 GB of internal storage space. No additional apps have been installed yet, except for some apps that came with the ROM, and the stock HTC apps that came with the phone.

**How-to**

You will need root and S-OFF before you continue. It's also possible to install this ROM with S-ON, but it will require some additional steps, for more details see the developers website. You will also need a custom recovery like Clock Work Mod (CWM) or 4Ext Recovery. The latter is recommended. You will also need to flash stock HBOOT, if you don't have that already. You will find the stock HBOOT on [AlphaRev](http://www.alpharev.nl/) website.

1. Go to the [download page](https://supernova.droidzone.in/supernova-rom-home/resources/download-links/) of developers website.
2. Download "SuperNova 2.4.0.1 Extreme ROM". You will see at least three mirror download links. Here's one direct link to [Dev-Host](https://supernova.droidzone.in/downloads/114).
3. Power off the phone.
4. Enter HBOOT on the phone.
5. Enter recovery (I used 4Ext Touch Recovery).
6. Format and partition the SD card with one Ext4 partition and one FAT32.
7. Power off the phone and take out the SD card.
8. Mount your SD card to the computer.
9. Copy the Supernova_2.4.0.1_signed.zip file to the SD card.
10. Put the SD card in the phone.
11. Enter recovery and choose "update from zip".
12. Select the file above. This will now flash the new ROM.
13. Reboot the phone. First boot will take longer time than usual.
14. When you get to the setup wizard, skip setting up a Google account.
15. Reboot the phone. You will see a blue LED go and off. This means Data2SD is loaded and working.
16. Now you can setup your Google account and Wi-Fi, and what not.

Remember, complete installation instructions can be found [here](https://supernova.droidzone.in/category/installation/). That web page can be overwhelming, especially for newbies, which is why I tried to put it in a more condensed form here.

If you run into the "Download was unsuccessful please try again" message when downloading apps, this means that the app you're trying to download is too big and the Android Market cache is too small. This problem is covered in the [FAQ](https://supernova.droidzone.in/category/faq/) at developers website, it's question 28.

The suggested workaround involves using Scriptmanager app and a script, and this must be done every time you reboot. But I have found that installing the latest version of Play Store (replacement for Android Market) manually solves the problem permanently.

Here's a short how-to on that too.

1. Download the APK file for [Play Store](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/04/09/download-new-google-play-store-4-0-25/).
2. Connect the phone to the computer. If prompted, choose to mount as
   disk drive.
3. Copy the APK file to the SD card.
4. Disconnect the phone.
5. Go to menu, settings, applications, and enable unknown sources.
6. Start a file manager app (I used ES File Explorer, but ASTRO is good
   too).
7. Browse to the file (/mnt/sdcard/) and tap it to open. You'll be
   prompted if you want to replace a system app. Tap OK to continue.

Comment: I will try this out and see how well it works. If it's very good I might write a short step by step guide for future visitors.

Comment: That looks like a miracle -- where does the extra space come from? 304 MB and 1.86 GB looks a little different :) Is that total space, or remaining space (so with your first screenshot, you had just filled it up)?

Comment: The extra space comes from the SD card. That's remaining space... and total space... I mean that's what it said when I just booted up the first time, without any additional apps installed. I created a 2 GB Ext4 partition on the SD card. This is combined with the 147 MB free user space that's normally available on the phone when it's new (the stock HBOOT layout). You would maybe expect 2 GB + 0.147 GB to be 2.147 GB. It's less than that, probably because some of that memory is addressed to things like GPU, and of course some of the apps added by developer.

Comment: To me that rather looks like mount points being switched (i.e. `/data` now resides on your 2 GB SDCard partition). The fact that you have to create the partition before flashing the ROM seems to support that. You could verify it executing the `mount` and `df` commands from a terminal or via `adb shell`. Everything else (including Data2SD) would not explain why the device displays that amount for *internal storage* (which it assumes is mounted at `/data`).

Comment: When in `adb shell`, how do I use the `mount` and `df` commands? Do you want me to use them together somehow? Do I just type `mount` to view mounting points, and then `df` to view total and available space? Give me an example, I'm not very familiar with linux.

Comment: You can see the output of both commands above. It says that `/system/data` has 151168K total. That's 147 MB. And available is 37356K or 36 MB. This is the actual internal memory, right? For `/data` it says 2064144K or 2015 MB total and 1619288K or 1581 MB available. Does this make any sense?

Comment: When I mount the SD card to the computer Windows says that total space is 27.2 GB. It should say 29.8 GB since it is a 32 GB card. So that's 2.6 GB missing, probably residing on the Ext4 partition.

Comment: Yupp, as expected: 2 GB on `/data`, that's your new partition on the SDCard. Then it seems to have re-partitioned the internal NAND (`/dev/block/mtdblock*`) to make use of what previously was used for `/data`: `/cache` now has 40 MB available, `/system` 250 MB, `/system/data` 148 MB, summing up to 438 MB (which they definitly did not have before: 512 MB NAND - 438 MB just leaves 74 MB (which is used by partitions not mounted and thus not listed above, such as e.g. `/recovery`). Careful when switching to another ROM which might not expect this partitioning :)

Comment: 32 GB is the *brutto capacity* of the card. Even with ony one partition on it, and a completely empty file system, you would not have 32 GB available. There's always a little "wasted space" ;) My single-partitioned 32 GB card shows up on my tablet as "29,27 GB total" -- so take away the 2 GB of your extra partition, and numbers match perfectly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8916/discussion-between-sammy-and-izzy)